# R: Use of save versions prior to 2 is deprecated with a RDA file

Tags: r

I'm working on a project and while trying to use the next file R (RStudio 3.4.0) keeps giving me this output:

> ```
> Error in load("pob_mun.Rda") : 
>   bad restore file magic number (file may be corrupted) -- no data loaded
> In addition: Warning message:
> file ‘pob_mun.Rda’ has magic number 'X'
>   Use of save versions prior to 2 is deprecated
> ```

I've used both of the next instructions without success:
`load ("pob_mun.Rda")`, or `source ("pob_mun.Rda")`.

While I've noticed this error happens not so seldom as I thought, what is weird for me is that all solutions I've seen are related to other formats, not the proper of R.

Any advice?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [workspace cannot be loaded in server, file has magic number 'RDX3'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57242296/workspace-cannot-be-loaded-in-server-file-has-magic-number-rdx3)