# workspace cannot be loaded in server, file has magic number 'RDX3'

Tags: r

I've been looking through other SO posts and I've seen that people had a similar problem to mine before. However, in my case when I load my RData workspace in RStudio it works just fine. However, when I try to load it in the server I get the following error:

Error in load(file = "/home/ubuntu/myfile.RData") : 
  bad restore file magic number (file may be corrupted) -- no data loaded
In addition: Warning message:
file ‘myfile.RData’ has magic number 'RDX3'
  Use of save versions prior to 2 is deprecated

I've loaded similar RData files in the server before and it always worked fine. The same file is loaded without any problems in RStudio as I said, but somehow the server doesn't like it

Comment: Same problem with any results!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you update R in your computer recently? If you did, from R 3.5.0, RData are saved using version 3 by default (RDX3). If you have an earlier version of R in your server, you probably need to save your data using the right version for your server (updating R in your server is another option). Please check the option `version` in the help of the `save` command to learn how to do that.